# Can I mine bitcoin testnet coins with my regular bitcoin asic miner?

Tags: mining-pools, testnet, asic

Is it possible to use my bitcoin asic miner to mine testnet bitcoin coins? Is there special software I need? can I join a testnet pool or is there even such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... they both use SHA256. However, be aware that Bitcoin Test Net and Bitcoin are different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should works since they both use the same algotherm but just a different network.